# Anyone encountered this? "Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer (56)"

Tags: cartthrob, error

Without making any changes to a website, and without the hosting company making any changes to  the server, a site using CT has suddenly started throwing this error using the EE default error template: "Error: Failure when receiving data from the peer (56)"

This happens when someone tries to get to the checkout page. Has anyone experienced anything like this before? It happens whether someone's logged in or not in every browser I could test.

Chris from CT is already looking into it, but I thought I'd see if anyone had ever experienced this before.

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved: turns out USPS made changes to their API which caused live rates to fail and throw the error.